# Ionic v3, xCode deploying an old version of the app to simulator and device

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

I tried removing the app all together, clean build and run again, but it always deploys an old version of the app. i.e. simple changes as updated titles, etc. are just not present at all.

I do see all these changes if i run "ionic serve" but with run or emulate or even going through xcode it just doesnt work and deploys an old version (not sure where it gets it from, as I did remove platform and add it again).

Also seems like the only way for any changes to be displayed on device/simulator is to change the version/build numbers EVERY time we want to run in the device/simulator. The second time that we run with same number/build it goes back to the original app.

my env setting below, pls help, I also have cocoapods installed.

```
cli packages: (/Users/terr4x/upwork/powermonkey/mm-app/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.9.4
npm        : 5.6.0 
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running emulator with live-reload?

What might help with iOS is:

```
xcodebuild clean
```

Before running ionic cordova emulate/build

Comment: I tried running with and without reload, either way my changes are not displayed in the installation. I have tried deploying to device with ionic cordova emulate and with xcode directly, none work for me.

Comment: Seems like the only way this "works" is with the following steps.  1. if I remove platform ios, then add it again.  2. run ionic cordova emulate ios -lc . If I attempt to run it again, it goes back to installing an old version of the app without my changes (no idea where it gets it from). Also If before the first deployment I open xcode, it never deploys my changes either. This never works for my device, only got it to work for simluiator and it stops working after first deployment, I am forced to repeat the steps above. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm not 100% sure but why are you using: ios-deploy : 1.9.2 , don't have that in my ionic info.

Comment: Also do you have cordova-plugin-whitelist installed? Might be that ios is blocking the livereload server. A nodejs server hosts the liverload, pushing it to the device. Add the following in your config.xml <allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>

Comment: I managed to make live reload work in device and simulator but only the first time right after I add the platform. For this to work again, I need to remove platform, add it again, open xcode only to choose the signing settings (automatically managed signing). Now its important to leave xcode and close it right after this (without building wiht xcode). Then run ionic cordova run ios -lc... live reload works and proper version/changes are reflected on the device. [continues in next comment below]

Comment: [continue from above]   If i run the ionic cordova run ios -lc command again, it deploy an old version of the app that doesnt contain my changes (no idea where it comes from), and livereload doesnt work of course. Need to repeat steps above for it to work again

Comment: I cam across this exact issue yesterday! Very weird. Seems to load the changes from the platform/ios/build rather than from the www directory. What seemed to fix it for me was nuking my dependencies and installing everything again.

Comment: I tried staring the project in a whole diff folder all together, same thing happens. Weird thing is this only happens with this particular project. When I start a New Ionic 3 project all works just fine.